Datastore flow stuck
I'm looking to read my DataStore for Feature Flags I have saved there. DataStore returns a flow, which makes sense but I do really need to read it once at the moment. No fancy logic. Listening to live changes is less important right now but might be in the future.
What happens is, when I try to read the data, it gets stuck somewhere as if my function never emitted values.
Here's the code:
The actual read from data store
fun getDataOrDefault(key: String, defaultValue: Boolean): Flow<Boolean> =
    dataStore.data
        .catch { exception ->
            when (exception) {
                is IOException -> emit(emptyPreferences())
                else -> throw exception
            }
        }.map { pref ->
            pref[booleanPreferencesKey(key)] ?: defaultValue
        }

Now, I have a list of keys that I want to pass and read values for
Read multiple values
fun getBoolEntries(vararg keys: String): Flow<Pair<String, Boolean>> = flow {
        keys.forEach { emit(it) }
    }.onEach {
        Log.i("DBGG", "Key: $it")
    }.flatMapMerge { key ->
         getDataOrDefaultOrDefault(key, false).map { Pair(key, it) }
    }

ViewModel read
// _viewState is a StateFlow
//.....
viewModelScope.launch {
    val flags = dataStoreRepository.getBoolEntries(
        KEY_1,
        KEY_2,
        KEY_3,//... and so on
    ).flowOn(Dispatchers.IO).toList()

    _viewState.emit(
        ConfigState.Active(flags)
    )
}

It never finishes and I can't emit a new state. What am I missing?

That's not how the datastore or flows in general should be used.
The datastore returns a flow of all its preferences in its dataStore.data property. Flows are suposed to be transformed, and only be collected at the latest possible moment. In your case that is the UI. Everything up until then, including the viewmodel, only uses map operations and the likes to transform that flow.
In your case that means you only need something like this in your datastore class:
fun getBoolEntries(vararg keys: String): Flow<Map<String, Boolean>> =
    dataStore.data
        .catch { exception ->
            when (exception) {
                is IOException -> emit(emptyPreferences())
                else -> throw exception
            }
        }.map { pref ->
            keys.associateWith { pref[booleanPreferencesKey(it)] ?: false }
        }

When called this returns a map of all requested keys with their currennt setting (true/false). It is wrapped in a flow, because these settings may change, and in that case the flow would emit a new map of all settings.
In your view model you can then simply retrieve this flow (assuming dataStoreRepository exposes the datastore function to the view model) and map it to your state object like this:
private val _viewState = dataStoreRepository
    .getBoolEntries(
        KEY_1,
        KEY_2,
        KEY_3,//... and so on
    )
    .map {
        ConfigState.Active(it)
    }

That's it, no dedicated coroutines are needed, no manual emissions into newly created flows, just leveraging the existing flow by simply transforming its content is enough.

I will try your solution, to experiment a bit. However my _viewState must not change every time I have a change in DataStore. If I have remote update of my flags it will trigger a state update which in turn will change my UI. That's undesirable effect. It must stay in a specific state until I'm ready to poll values instead of event-driven react

Also, I understand "That's not how the datastore or flows in general should be used" but that's just poor design. It should be designed around how people use it and not the other way around. My use case requires  to get a snapshot of my data and do something else. Then maybe I'll read the data again. Maybe...

Don't use a hammer on a screw. It doesn't work well. It's not that the screw is poorly designed, you are just using the wrong tool. Either stick with what you know and replace the shiny, new screw with a plain, old nail, or learn how to use a screwdriver. Technology shouldn't be designed "around how people use [old technology]", it should be designed to efficiently solve a problem. It's up to the user to properly use the new technology. Otherwise we would still be throwing stones and poking with sticks.

If you don't need flows, don't use flows: suspend fun preferences() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { dataStore.data.first() }. That said, you seem to expose this data in the view model, so you want it to be visible to the user. But I don't see a reason why you want to change that data without wanting the user to see this change. Why change it in the first place? You are getting in a lot of trouble regarding your single source of truth if you do not update the UI in this case. This will come back and bite you, especially when you start using Compose for your UI.

Exactly my point. I have a nail but the shop is selling me a screwdriver. I don't have a choice other than buying it and using it like a hammer. Leaving metaphors aside, there is nothing "new" about Flow. And there is nothing inherently better about "new". It all depends on the use case. A good tech is backwards compatible while offering the "new" shiny stuff. A good example is Retrofit (sounds like a pun). It can be used in a procedural way or reactive (RxJava or Flow) but you can choose what you need. In the end I've done exactly this dataStore.data.first() but it's a hack.

An update in the reactive chain to my state might not represent the actual state of the app. If I have an update in DataStore but my state is still Loading and the app is waiting for other stuff, emission of ConfigState.Active(flags) would be an error. Anyhow this discussion is most useful

Any idea why .toList() doesn't work in my example? Even if I've used dataStore.data.first() I'm curious what's happening there.

I do not even know what toList() is. There is a function of this name defined for Flow, but that takes an additional parameter (a mutable list that is filled one by one whenever a new value becomes available) so that's not it. toList() is also defined on Pair which creates a list of two elements, the first and the second. You would need to call first on the flow and then apply this function, but that would make even less sense. To answer your question: There is no toList() function for Flow<Pair<String, Boolean>>, that''s why it doesn't work.
